# How does java guarateee reserved memory

Tags: java, linux, jvm

Checking for memory usage by **stack** using this command:

```
jcmd $pid VM.native_memory summary
```

I can see that reserved memory is different from committed.

- ```
                 Thread (reserved=18561KB, committed=1085KB)
                        (thread #18)
                        (stack: reserved=18476KB, committed=1000KB)
                        (malloc=63KB #99) 
                        (arena=22KB #35)
  ```

Reserved is about 1MB (default for stack). Committed in fact is physical reserved. I read that java save memory for stack while is not totally used.

Running command like top I can see just committed usage.

What does java/SO do in order to reserve this memory without being counted by RSS (linux memory measure) statistics?

Could other process use this memory due that is no physically reserved?

**Note: jdk11**
**SO Linux**

Comment: The operating system does it, not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does java/SO do in order to reserve this memory without being counted by RSS (linux memory measure) statistics?

This kind of "reservation" is based on the concept of [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The JVM calls [`mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to reserve an address space. Initially these addresses are just numbers not backed by physical pages. On the first access to a virtual page, a page fault happens, and the OS handles it by allocating the backing storage (physical RAM or a swap space).

> Could other process use this memory due that is no physically reserved?

In short, yes. A longer answer - depends on the OS settings, specifically, [`vm.overcommit_memory`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) and [`vm.overcommit_ratio`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) sysctls. The default settings allow overcommitment - i.e. it's possible to allocate more virtual memory than available physical RAM + swap (because applications often do not use all virtual memory they reserve).

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that in any modern operating system, "memory" is virtual.

"Reserved" memory is actually just address space that is assigned to a particular use.  What this means is mostly just some adjustment of data structures that track address-space use.

"Committed" memory is a little more wiggly. Mostly it just means that the physical memory that **could be** needed is tracked against some notion of the maximum commit that is available.  There's generally no notion that actual physical RAM is somehow allocated to the process at this point; at best, pagefile space may be reserved.

(If you want actual for-sure RAM, you need to "pin" committed pages into physical memory).

Actual RAM isn't assigned until a page is touched; and even after that, it can be taken away again, by the dynamics of paged virtual memory, in part depending on what else is happening on the hardware.